# How to build Multi ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, dictionary, concurrency, guava, multimap

guava library has useful `MultuMap` to replace `Map<Object, Collection>` to avoid null checks.

I cannot find analog `MultiMap` for `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Does it exist ?

Does `Multimaps.forMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<Object, Object>());` correct?

### P.S.

initialization:

```
private Multimap<Object, ComplexCalcStrategy> strategies = HashMultimap.<Object, ComplexCalcStrategy>create();
```

first thread:

```
for (Integer optionId : strategy.getOptions()) {
            strategies.put(optionId, strategy);
  }
```

second thread:

```
Collection<ComplexCalcStrategy> strategiesThatNeedUpdating = strategies.get(mktDataChange.getOptionId());
for (ComplexCalcStrategy strategy : strategiesThatNeedUpdating) { 
     updateMarketData(strategy.getStrategy(), mktDataChange);
}
```

Now this code leads to `ConcurrentModificationexception`.

Comment: I would be surprised if it was thread safe, but otherwise it should work.

Comment: You could use a ConcurrentHashMap and you choice of thread safe collection, but I suspect you would need to combine these yourself based on your use case.

Comment: There is `Multimaps.synchronized*Multimap()` methods. Thread safe, but maybe not with the level of concurrency you would expect...

Comment: @fge I am iterating over map and don't want to get concurrentModificationException

Comment: Have you tried using a Hashtable instead of a Map? http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/03/hashmap-vs-hashtable-difference-with-example-java-interview-questions.html

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I added more details in the topic. Can you help to answer something concrete ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow You can avoid ConcurrentModificationExceptions with `synchronizedMultimap`; you just have to do it correctly by synchronizing your iteration.

Comment: @Louis Wasserman I think that it is bad approach because full map locks if I adds element to list which was used as value.

Comment: Correct.  But the reason there isn't a concurrent Multimap design is because there isn't a reliable way to do any better.

Answer (score 0):

If i remembar correctly `HashMultimap.create();` and then `ImmutableSetMultimap.Builder`.

Comment: After you build you get an immutable constant view, that can not mutate - it is thread safe (https://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSetMultimap.Builder.html ). But clearly only first level and it is not deeply immutable. AFAIK, you can not have deep immutability in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace those sections with

initialization:

```
private final Map<Integer, Set<ComplexCalcStrategy>> strategies = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

first thread:

```
for (Integer optionId : strategy.getOptions()) {
    strategies.computeIfAbsent(optionId, k -> Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>()))
              .add(strategy);
}
```

second thread:

```
for (ComplexCalcStrategy strategy : strategies.getOrDefault(optionId, Collections.emptySet())) { 
     updateMarketData(strategy.getStrategy(), mktDataChange);
}
```

Comment: I use java 6 version

Comment: *computeIfAbsent* method is absent in java 6

Comment: Perhaps it's time to upgrade.  Java 6 and 7 are no longer publicly supported.  There is not equivalent in Java 6.  Java 8 should also be faster.

Comment: unfortunately we can not do it at the moment

Comment: @gstackoverflow in that case I would wait until you can.  Or I would consider using a strategy which assumes the Map isn't changed often and you replace it every time it get updated, this would allow concurrent reads.

Comment: @gstackoverflow another option is to make the option id small and use an AtomicReferenceArray (Java 5.0) instead of a concurrent map.

Comment: This implementation can potentially have memory leak during entry removal.

Comment: @ssgao That would depend on how remove is implemented, though it wasn't required by the OP.